# pyspark df.write writing(parquet) to S3 but data is missing in half the columns

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

Using EMR w 4 workers and 1 master

- Release label:emr-5.24.0
- Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.5
- Applications:Spark 2.4.2, Hive 2.3.4

I am able to process my data and create the correct dataframe in pyspark. But when I write (parquet)the df out to S3, the files are indeed placed in S3 in the correct location, but 3 of the 7 columns are suddenly missing data.

Can anyone explain what I need to do to fix this?   Here are the relevant code and result screenshots.  I've renamed some columns in the screenshots to maintain privacy.

My code:

```
# For multi tables
df_multi.show(5)
df_multi.printSchema()
print("\n At line 578, after show(), writing to EDL\n")
df_multi.write.mode("append").parquet(multi_s3_bucket_dir)
print("\n  SCRIPT COMPLETED  \n")
```

A screenshot of the output when the script runs.  I run it as nohup and redirect stdin & sterr to a file to see later:
[image: screenshot while running]

And here is the output, read from S3 using Athena:
[image: Athena query]

Answer (score 1):

Mea culpa.  Problem solved.   My column names in the df did not exactly match the column names in the Athena DDL.  Because parquet is 'schema-on-read', the system created a schema matching the df, but it could only import those columns whose name DID match, leaving the rest empty.

Lesson learned.